# Which javascript datepicker plugin/library to use for maximum flexibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I know generic javascript datepickers are plentiful but they all look unremarkable. Even the jQuery UI datepicker looks a little dated. I am fine with using one that looks rough now, but later on we will want to improve the way it looks (make it more in line with the rest of the UI) and I don't want to shoot myself in the foot by picking one that will be hard to change. I am talking only about cosmetic CSS/HTML changes (or templating)

Which date/calendar JavaScript plugin would you recommend from a template flexibility angle?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Jquery UI, http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

so that you don't have to put any more libraries. It has almost all the functionalities you need along with good documentation. see an e.g below

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    // the jquery calendar
    $( "#yourId" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "both", // show on clicking image as well as text box
        yearRange: "2000:2030",
        buttonImage: imagePath+"/b-calendar.gif", // custom image
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true
        ,changeMonth: true
        ,changeYear: true
        //,showAnim:"slideDown"
        ,buttonText: 'Show Calendar'
        //,showButtonPanel : true
        ,prevText: 'Previous Month'
        ,nextText: 'Next Month'
        ,beforeShow: function (textbox, instance) { // work around 4 alignment 
            instance.dpDiv.css({
                    marginTop: (-textbox.offsetHeight) + 'px',
                    marginLeft: textbox.offsetWidth + 30+ 'px'
        });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I've always found the jQuery UI Datepicker to be great. There's plenty of themes for jQuery UI or you can [roll your own](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). It definitely does not look dated if you take the time to make it look how you want it to.

Comment: I wish every browser implements date/time picker as part of HTML5 standard, like Opera does in <input type="date">